# Can only one now imply every future?

Tags: cosmology, time

In logic, A implies B, if B is always true in instances where A is true. 
Obviously, there can only be one possible future, for every potential now, that is, in all instances where a certain now is true, the same future must be true. Otherwise, the flow of time would be totally unpredictable and random. But how is it the other way around, going backwards in time? Can the same future be derived from several different pasts or now, making it intractable, or is there only one now that can imply every future?

I find that if there are indeed several potential nows that can  lead to the same future, then this will eventually cause time to repeat itself in a loop. Furthermore, it will lead to a progressively conform array of timelines.

Comment: How many possible futures exist is not a scientific question. Neither the present, nor the future are knowable in quantum mechanics, so it's not clear to me how you want to get from one unknown to another. There are certain invariants that can't change, so the future is limited, but within those limits its exponentially wide open at all times. For the same reason a complete reconstruction of the past is also not possible. Many different pasts could have led to the same present.

Comment: How do you define "scientific question"? Isn't all questions scientific in the sense that questions are one of the seeds of knowledge?

Comment: A 'scientific question' simply is a question which may be (in)validated by use of the scientific method. For example 'How many times can I cut a watermelon in half and what is the smallest unit of nature?'. A non scientific question would be 'Does god exist' or 'Are humans inherently good or evil?'. Your question can be done mathematically, but cannot be validated scientifically due to reasons @CuriousOne stated above.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more about philosophy than physics.

Answer (score 0):

> Can only one now imply every future?

In other words, "is the mathematical model of nature deterministic", a one to one correspondence , or a one to many?.

Classical mechanics and electrodynamics are deterministic by construction. The parameters of the future solution have one to one correspondence with the parameters of the past. Thermodynamics if dependent on classical statistical mechanics in principle is deterministic, but in effect one works with probabilities because of the complexity of large numbers of constants that would determine an enormous number of trajectories , with the possible errors.

Quantum mechanics is probabilistic in nature, and mainstream physics accepts that quantum mechanics is the underlying level of all of observed natural phenomena. The equations of quantum mechanics determine probabilities, not fixed trajectories , thus from individual events detected in the future, one can only project a probability of their coming from some specific parameters of the past .

> Can the same future be derived from several different pasts or now, making it intractable, or is there only one now that can imply every future?

There exists a probability that a same within measurement errors and the Heisenberg uncertainty future can come from different pasts , also bounded by measurement errors and the heisenberg uncetainty.

Since every quantum mechanical estimate is probabilistic, there is no way to generate the circularity you envisage. Only a fuzziness in the future correlated to a fuzziness in the past.

I do not see the logic of you last paragraph or agree with it, even for a classical universe:

> I find that if there are indeed several potential nows that can lead to the same future, then this will eventually cause time to repeat itself in a loop. Furthermore, it will lead to a progressively conform array of timelines.

Time is a coordinate going to + infinity, what repetitions?

Comment: Why claim that classical mechanics is deterministic? Are you going to ban certain potentials to eliminate Norton's Dome? Or eliminate certain initial velocities to avoid the multiple solutions that $\vec F=m\vec a$ allows?

Comment: @Timaeus  it is deterministic once all the constants for the solution are known. One can calculate where earth was as many years ago as wanted , given the constants and the equations ( admittedly numerically)

Comment: I asked *why* you claimed determinism. For computing the Earth's motions under just gravity the claim depends on the very specific form of the gravitational force. That doesn't tell you that other force laws give unique solutions, and other force laws do give non unique solutions. Now you seem to claim there are magic constants that would give a unique solution to, say, Norton's Dome. And again I'd ask why you make such a fantastical claim.

Comment: @Timaeus  I looked up Norton's dome. It is just a peculiar solution. Are you claiming that classical mechanics is not deterministic? I thought the the whole fight with the claims of deterministic substructure of quantum mechanics is about this.

Comment: There is nothing in Newton's three laws of motion that gives determinism. Norton's Dome is merely one example of many. Some people might want classical mechanics to be deterministic and if they do, the onus or responsibility is on them to create additional restrictions or laws to create a deterministic physical theory. Newton didn't make a deterministic theory and Newton didn't even actually think particles always followed his laws. And most people don't even try to make a deterministic theory, it's easier to pretend the theory you have is deterministic and tell people it is and move on

Comment: @Timaeus  I am not into philosophy of science. I do know that classical theories are considered     deterministic in contrast to quantum mechanics which is considered probabilistic as far as predictions for measurements and hind casting on individual solutions goes,and that is the use I am making of the term.

Comment: Yes, it is much easier to pretend that a theory is deterministic than to make a deterministic theory. And if you wrongly tell people that your theory is deterministic when it isn't then they can go and tell other people, and those other people can tell even more people, and then when enough people think the same untrue thing as you thought then you can even try to call that folk tale "science". But *why* would you do that? It doesn't help people to understand the universe, so *why* do it?

Answer (score 0):

There can be many possible futures. It's a staple of standard quantum mechanics that you list all the possible futures and state the relative frequency of getting the different results.

Such a prediction is falsifiable in many ways, either by doing the experiment and getting a result that isn't on the list. Or elese doing the experiment many times and getting a relative frequencies of the different results that is very different than the relative frequencies predicted by the theory.

It's like if you rolled a dice and got a seven. That would definitely contradict the theory that you get 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, or 6 all with equal relative frequencies.

Or it would be like if you rolled a dice a trillion times and got six 99% of the time. That would definitely raise doubt against the theory that you get 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, or 6 all with equal relative frequencies.

Now even without quantum mechanics the same thing happens. A theory restricts certain observations either by outright saying they don't happen or by saying they happen at a specific frequency relative to other outcomes.

So for instance $\vec F=m\vec a$ forbids any function $\vec r(t)$ that doesn't satisfy $\vec F=m\vec a$. And if you pick a force law that allows multiple solutions to $\vec F=m\vec a$ (such as Norton's Dome) then you can still do science by proposing a theory to predict the rate you get the different results.

If different solutions to Norton's Dome predict a relative frequency for the different amounts of time it takes to go from A to B, then it allows multiple pasts when moving away from the Dome as well as multiple futures when moving towards the Dome.